# upgrading Kafka AND using newer scala version

Tags: apache-kafka

Some time ago, somebody at my company downloaded, unpacked, configured and started using kafka_2.11-2.4.1.tgz. Now I need to upgrade to 2.8.1. This version does not exist with scala 2.11. Can I just unpack kafka_2.13-2.8.1.tgz and start using that, or does the scala version need to be considered? I'm using openjdk11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be recommended to upgrade as high as possible on patch releases (such as 2.8.2). Realistically, you should upgrade to 3.x release.

Regarding Scala, look at the download page more carefully

> [The version] only matters if you are using Scala and you want a version built for the same Scala version you use. Otherwise any version should work

In other words, if you're not compiling Scala code directly on your brokers, then you only need Java runtime, and Kafka already includes the Scala runtime libraries it needs for whatever version you select...

Make sure you fully read the upgrade notes. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_8_1